# how to add picture box control and label control dynamically in list view control

Tags: asp.net

I want to display picture box control and label into list view for particular record. And all the records comes from the database. I tried it but i am only able to display only single image but i want to display all images with label 
the code I try is

```
DataSet ds3 = load.LoadNewlyAddedBook();
        DataTable dt3 = ds3.Tables[0];
        lstViewNewAdd.Items.Clear();
        int count = dt3.Rows.Count;
        for (int a = 0; a < count; a++)
        {
            DataRow dtRow = dt3.Rows[a];
            if (dtRow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi3 = new ListViewItem(dtRow["BookName"].ToString());
                PictureBox p1 = new PictureBox();
                p1.Size = new Size(80, 100);
                Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])(dtRow["BookImage"]);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                p1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                p1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = dtRow["BookName"].ToString();
                lstViewNewAdd.Controls.Add(p1);
                //lstViewNewAdd.Controls.Add(lbl);
                //lvi3.SubItems.Add(p1);

                //lstViewNewAdd.Items.Add(lvi3);
            }
        }
```

Please suggest me any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you google around?

There are lot of links that can help you

http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/04/24/faq-displaying-image-from-database-to-gridview-control.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/05/26/show-images-on-grid-view-from-file-stream.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20782/Displaying-Images-from-a-Database-in-a-GridView

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20971/Thumbnail-Images-in-GridView-using-C

Comment: I have searched for it,but I didn't get any proper article.As I want to add picture box and label control in the same row of List View control.